# Is there a way to clear the sharepoint online cache

Tags: sharepoint-online, administration, cache

I am working on a sharepoint online classic team site, and i have updated its navigation links. but some users have reported that the old links are still showing when they click on the back button on their browsers. now i am pretty sure that this is a caching problem on the users' browsers, but my question if i can from sharepoint online side, to force all browsers to read the fresh data? in other words to force the browser cache to get expired, so the users' browsers will have to read the fresh data from the sharepoint server?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am afraid that we cannot force the browser cache to get expired from SharePoint online side.

The users’ browser cache only can be cleared by themselves.

You could remind the users to clear browser cache.